# How to escape newline in regex scan

Tags: ruby, regex

```
str = "This\n is a sample text for test"
str.scan(/\S.{0,15}\S(?=\s|$)|\S+/)
# => ["This", "is a sample text", "for test"]
```

Here, it splits when the newline (`\n`) is present. I actually want the output as,

```
 ["This\n is a", "sample text for", "test"]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `/m` modifier which allows the dot to match newlines:

```
str.scan(/\S.{0,15}\S(?=\s|\z)|\S+/m)
```

Also, I suggest you use `\z` instead of `$` because `$` matches the end of a line; `\z` is the only way to force Ruby to match the end of the string. It doesn't matter in this example, but it's a good habit to get into. Ruby differs from all other regex flavors in these two points.